# Plesk 9.2 email redirect stopped working after update from 9.0

Tags: plesk, qmail

Im really having a problem with this one. My server is a linux CentOS based running Plesk 9.2
After the update my email forwarding stopped working! Plesk uses qmail to manage emails. Basically whatever I do in the webpased Plesk panel just does not work with email forwarding. Does anyone know what can be the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: i have the same problem with plesk 10.2

Answer (score 0):

I wish, haveing a similar problem but with and older version of plesk. After I rebuilt the qmail queue email redirection stoped working. Strange because everything looks fin in the psa mail log